# Fastest way to copy 1TB safely over the wire

Tags: linux, file-transfer

I want to transmit a 1TB file over the internet. I have control over both machines (sender unix, receiver linux). I can open FTP, OpenVPN, NFS, ...

So far resuming for some reason is not stable on FTP, so I cut the file in 1GB pieces and transmit file per file, then md5 on the other side. It's very annoying.

I have between 3 and 6 mbytes/sec to the other site. Which is a pretty decent speed.

I want it to be safe and I want resuming if it fails.
I tried NFS - no resuming.

Is there a cleaner, safer way?

Comment: Should we assume a Linux OS?

Comment: yes (*nix), I will update the question

Comment: If you can afford it (costs and availability), you could sent the disc and copy it locally. This doesn't cover the explicit question though.

Comment: `rsync` would do I think

Comment: I tested rsync - it resumes after restart (or network issues) and copies successfully (md5 checked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need restart, rsync is probably the way to go.  One of the fastest ways over a network, I've found is with "Samba" -- but to get excellent performance it usually needs to be tuned for the environment.  But what I mean by "fast" is on a 1Gbit ethernet,
125MB/s writes and 119MB/s reads.  The 125MB/s writes are as fast as you are going to get unless your payload is able to be compressed -- i.e. a 1TB text file would likely compress to 1/10th the size.

Note... problem w/rsync, "direct" is that it generally uses some other protocol (rsh/ssh) to do do the transfer -- if you use rsync over 'ssh' you will incur an encryption cost, which on a good machine adds a ceiling of 140-160MB/s.  That will usually drive up latency on a network connection and slow down overall transfer be 50% or more.

So the fastest way depends on what type of network you have in place between the two machines. Slow-ish Internet speeds (i.e. .5-10MB/s), or a local area network (w/1Gb or perhaps even
10Gb).

If transfer speed is most important and more so than overall
speed, i'd "prep" the file for transfer by running it through
a good compressor (like xz or 7z) -- BUT that will take a large chunk of time by itself (so overall time is likely to be larger).  But if actual transfer speed is more important, then compression becomes a good way to cut down on that.

It really depends on where your priorities are and how much time you want to spend optimizing the transfer speed.    Overall, though, I think sirlancelot gave the right answer, just that there can be many mitigating factors depending on your priorities.

Comment: Try 500MB/s with AES-128 on a CPU that supports AES-NI - any halfway decent modern CPU will. Also, 125MB/s is literally impossible with a 1Gbit/s line - there *will* be overhead, at the transport and network layers even without considering the application protocol. I'm not certain I trust your numbers.

Comment: Without very significant compression (which is only achievable on extremely low entropy data), you're never going to see 125 MB/s in any direction on GbE. Protocol overhead at the IP, TCP/UDP, and application layers will account for more than a trivial amount of the throughput, *especially* over the public Internet. On a point to point link (e.g. a patch cable between two systems' NICs) you may be able to get closer using jumbo IP frames and a very low chattiness protocol, but even if you could get it to burst to 124 MB/s, it would never sustain that consistently.

Comment: And even with compression, you're still going to be sending less than 125 MB/s of compressed data per second, no matter how much actual (decompressed) data is being sent. Obviously if you 7-zip a file full of a quadrillion zero bytes, you can achieve transfer speeds in the terabytes per second (of decompressed data) by sending the couple-KB 7z image over even a WAN network. But that's disingenuous to the point.

Comment: Sorry, but it was measured multiple times.  Other people on the samba list have had similar experiences.  You have to realize I'm using 9k packets at the IP level, and generally around 32MB of buffer space/socket as default.  On the windows side you allocate packet buffers.  @ 4k of packet buffers x 9000 bytes=>nearly 18MB on the windows side for buffering.  The overhead is low -- the writes are faster because multiple packets can be outstanding w/out waiting for ACKS from the receiver.  @ Full duplex switched networking, there is no packet loss or retransmission.  (previous comment incomplet)

Comment: As for encryption speed, I've tried various ssh algorithms, but I don't think I've tried any hardware assisted algorithms.  If you want 500MB/s -- you have to be using hardware with specialized instructions.   As for the compression angle --- I very clearly stated it depended on what the poster's priorities were.  Was it minimum transmission time, or minimal time overall, I didn't get that they were going for fastest MB/s transfer rate, which is why I agreed that rsync would be good as it can be restarted...

Comment: WRT the 125MB xfer speed -- the nomenclature is misleading and a result of Gnu's - "dd" program changing specified units on the fly for inclusion in output.  I.e. 125MB from 'dd' = 125*10*\*6, which isn't what one might expect from using binary prefixes for input, like 'k'(2*\*10 or 1024), and 'M' (2*\*10**2).  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 5):

I think `rsync` allows resuming previous transfers.

```
$ rsync -aP src/ dest:dir/
```

[`man rsync`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html)

Comment: is it stable enough?

Comment: Yes, rsync has been around since late '90s and it's available on most Linux distros or available as a package to install.

Comment: resuming is problematic: If I transfer 1tb and the transfer stops at 500gb, and I then resume, rsync starts rehashing locally and remotely, which takes hours. Can I cache the hashing?